# Shopware 6 "You have requested a non-existent service "sales_channel_definition.ProductDefinition" after installing plugin

Tags: shopware

After installing the Channable plugin for Shopware 6 I received the following error.

```
Plugin could not be activated due to error message "You have requested a non-existent service "sales_channel_definition.Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition"
```

I haven't been able to find a solution for this, and Google turns up little.

Comment: Looks like the plugin developer messed something up. I would recommend to directly get in touch with them ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but if you are talking about that plugin https://store.shopware.com/en/res6026584109026f/channable-connector.html.

Looks like it is not available for Shopware 6 yet.

Comment: The Shopware 6 connector is provided in beta, and not yet available via the store.

Comment: In this case, i think, it is some issue in services.xml of that plugin. Looks like some dependencies are configured incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a plugin or app with a **services.xml** file that might cause you trouble. Try deactivating your plugins and enable them one by one.. when you have found the plugin, then look into the **services.xml** file in order to find the problem.